# Can pandas be used to pivot/transpose a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently have a table that I need to transform. The data set looks like this:

```
  Period   Course Teacher
0      1      Sci  Teach1
1      2      Art  Teach1
2      H     Span  Teach1
3      1       PE  Teach2
4      2       CS  Teach2
5      H     Conf  Teach2
6      1   AP Art  Teach3
7      2  Dig Art  Teach3
8      H   Health  Teach3
```

I would like it to look like the following:

```
    Teacher       H      P1       P2
0  Teacher1    Span     Sci      Art
1  Teacher2    Conf      PE       CS
2  Teacher3  Health  AP Art  Dig Art
```

Not sure how to go about this, or if it is something pandas would handle.

I have tried `df.transpose` which results in:

```
                    0        1        2  ...        6         7        8
Period          1        2        H  ...        1         2        H
 Course       Sci      Art     Span  ...   AP Art   Dig Art   Health
 Teacher   Teach1   Teach1   Teach1  ...   Teach3    Teach3   Teach3
```

I have tried using `df.groupby(['Teacher'])` which returns an error  grouper, exclusions, obj = get_grouper

I have searched for  `pivot`, `melt`, `transform`. Not sure of the language needed to search for examples of this type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe)

Comment: [Please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to look for existing questions before posting on Stack Overflow. I can literally [copy and paste your title into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Can+pandas+be+used+to+pivot%2Ftranspose+a+data+frame) and get relevant results right off the top.

Comment: Thank you for your response and thank you for editing my pasted data frame mess. I was searching on SO for how to get those to show up formatted properly. I did look at that Q but failed to see a match to my DF example, I'm sure it is there but I don't parse it. Would love to know how to get the formatting right on the copy and pasted output.

Comment: Now that you have received an answer, can you see how it relates to the answers at the other question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple approach using [**`df.pivot()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```py
df = df.pivot(index="Teacher", columns="Period", values="Course").reset_index()
df.columns = ["Teacher", "P1", "P2", "H"]
df = df[["Teacher", "H", "P1", "P2"]]

print(df)
```

---

```
  Teacher       H      P1       P2
0  Teach1    Span     Sci      Art
1  Teach2    Conf      PE       CS
2  Teach3  Health  AP Art  Dig Art
```

Answer (score 1):

`pivot_table` is definitively what you are looking for:

```
>>> (df.assign(Period=df['Period'].mask(df['Period'].str.isdigit(), other='P'+df['Period']))
       .pivot_table(index='Teacher', columns='Period', values='Course', aggfunc='first')
       .rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index())

  Teacher       H      P1       P2
0  Teach1    Span     Sci      Art
1  Teach2    Conf      PE       CS
2  Teach3  Health  AP Art  Dig Art
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I  create my DF and then use the code you have posted I get an error message: KeyError: 'Course'

Comment: What is the real name of your column?

Comment: Period, Course, Teacher are the column names.

Comment: Maybe you have trailing whitespace. What is the output of `print(df.columns)`?

Comment: Actually, I had leading whitespace on 2 of the columns. Thank you so. much. The more I learn about pandas the more I want to learn. Thanks again.